# How to override Django DeleteView without using Abstract Model and Manager

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to soft delete entry from my DB by overriding delete method in DeleteView but it is not working. Attribute active should be set to False. I can't use Abstract model and Manager because my parent model must originally have active attribute.
**my view**

```
class PersonDeleteView(DeleteView):
model = Person
template_name = 'contacts/deleteperson.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('persons')

def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        self.object.active = False 
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

**parent model**

```
class AddressEntry(models.Model):

GENDER = (
    ('Male', 'Male'),
    ('Female', 'Female'),
)
gender = models.CharField( max_length= 20, choices=GENDER, default='Male')   
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
birthdate = models.DateField()
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def soft_delete(self):
    self.active = False
    self.save()
```

**child model**

```
class Person(AddressEntry):
parentname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
job =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to save the instance after modifying it ?

```py
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        self.object.active = False
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: Yes, didn't work